# Getting error: 'WebHostBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseLamar'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, lamar

I see that there is support for ASP.NET Core 3.0 but what about 3.1? I've tried with no luck. Not sure if I am doing something dumb or if it is not supported?

I've installed the latest Nuget Packages:

- Lamar 4.0.0
- Lamar.Microsoft.DependencyInjection 4.0.2

And I am using:

```
var builder = new WebHostBuilder();
builder.UseLamar()
```

The file includes `using Lamar.Microsoft.DependencyInjection;` at the top.

But getting error: 
'WebHostBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseLamar'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Integration with ASP.Net Core](https://jasperfx.github.io/lamar/documentation/ioc/aspnetcore/) guide includes a note that states:

> If you are targeting .Net Core 3.0 and/or `netstandard2.1`, use the newly consolidated [HostBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-3.0) instead of the previous `IWebHostBuilder`.

A literal replacement for the code shown in the question would look like this:

```
var builder = new HostBuilder();
builder.UseLamar();
```

However, the typical setup code for creating a host builder, with a call to `UseLamar` added, would look something like this for 3.0+:

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseLamar()
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webHostBuilder =>
    {
        webHostBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
    });
```

The note I called out above links to the ASP.NET Core docs, which explains the generic host in much more detail: [.NET Generic Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-3.0).

Comment: Kirk, that got me pretty close. I had to add .Build().Run() to the end to make it run: Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseLamar()
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webHostBuilder =>
                    webHostBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>()).Build().Run();